# Проблема с односвязным списком и считыванием с файла в Си

Tags: c, файлы, структуры, односвязный-список, динамические-структуры

Есть такая структура

```
typedef struct student {
char name[100];
int year;
float average;
struct student *next;
} STUDENT;
```

Которая позже используется в функции, которая по неизвестной причине не работает. По-сути там создается односвязный список, который возвращается:

```
STUDENT **readFromFile(char *file){
FILE *fr;
if((fr = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}
int count;
fscanf(fr, "%d", &count);
STUDENT **head = NULL;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    STUDENT *temporary = (STUDENT*)malloc(sizeof(STUDENT));
    int j=0;
    while ((temporary->name[j] = getchar()) != '\n') {
        j++;
    }
    fscanf(fr, "%d", &temporary->year);
    fscanf(fr, "%f", &temporary->average);
    temporary->next=(*head);
    (*head) = temporary;
}
fclose(fr);
return head;
}
```

После компиляции каждый раз неизвестные ошибки, которые я не понимаю. Помогите

Comment: `STUDENT *temporary = (STUDENT*)(sizeof(STUDENT));`  *--Что это было, Майкл?!!! "Беда", сэр!!! (с)*

Comment: @Harry Спасибо за смешной ироничный ответ, а можно мне, тупому, пояснить, что здесь не так?

Comment: после считывания имени поставьте ноль. `temporary->name[j]='\00';`

Comment: Здесь нет места, а у меня времени, чтобы рассказывать с самого начала о динамической памяти. Вы здесь сказали примерно так - "Размер структуры STUDENT в байтах - это и есть адрес в памяти, в который мы будем писать данные." Понимаете? Просто вот в конкретное место в памяти, и неважно, что там - код, переменные, мало ли что...  См. https://metanit.com/cpp/c/5.8.php, https://ravesli.com/urok-85-dinamicheskoe-vydelenie-pamyati-operatory-new-i-delete/, https://learnc.info/c/memory_allocation.html. Но еще лучше - книга "С для чайников".

Comment: @AlexGlebe Считывания ***куда***?

Comment: @Harry наверное вы про то, что там нет malloc. Это вышло случайно уже когда я вставлял код сюда. В самом коде оно есть.

Comment: В массив `name`. @Harry

Comment: @AlexGlebe На момент написания вашего ответа temporary указывал, мягко говоря, пальцем в небо...

Comment: @Harry ещё раз пишу, что та ошибка возникла в ходе передачи кода на Stack Overflow. В коде malloc было

Comment: Простите, что не воспользовался машиной времени, и не посмотрел, как вы потом исправили код. Она у меня в ремонте. Не знаю, сможете ли вы меня простить, но я посыпаю голову пеплом и, упав на колени, припадаю к вашим стопам с просьбой о прощении комментария по тому тексту, который был в момент написания комментария...

Comment: @Harry ничего страшного. Не стоит драматизировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В основном ошибка использование указателя на указатель `STUDENT **head = NULL;`. После `(*head) = temporary;` произойдет запись в память по нулевому указателю и ошибка памяти. Поменяйте на обычный указатель `STUDENT *head = NULL;`.

Читаете буквы из консоли с помощью `getchar`. А надо из файла `fgetc`.

Потом при считывании имени забыли проставить конец строки `temporary->name[j]='\00';` и проследить за переполнением из-за длинного имени.

```
typedef struct student {
  char name[100];
  int year;
  float average;
  struct student *next;
} STUDENT;

# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

STUDENT * readFromFile(char *file){
  FILE *fr;
  if((fr = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
int count;
fscanf(fr, "%d", &count);
STUDENT * head = NULL ;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    STUDENT *temporary = (STUDENT*)malloc(sizeof(STUDENT));
    int j=0;
    while (j < 99 && (temporary->name[j] = fgetc(fr)) != '\n') {
        j++;
    }
    temporary->name[j]='\00';
    fscanf(fr, "%d", &temporary->year);
    fscanf(fr, "%f", &temporary->average);
    temporary->next=head;
    head = temporary;
}
fclose(fr);
return head;
}
```

Comment: дописал до вашего кода функцию мейн и програма все еще не работает. После компиляции просто получаю пустую командую строку не возвращает ни 1, ни 0:
int main(){
    STUDENT *head;
    head = readFromFile("E:\\CLionProjects\\untitled\\vstup.txt");
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("head is NULL");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

Comment: Проверил, нашёл ещё один баг `getchar` -> `fgetc`